# Cobb Douglas Production: Identification issues for technical change

Tags: production-function, cobb-douglas

It's well know that under a Cobb Douglas production function, capital and labor augmenting technical progress cannot be individually identified. Accordingly, people usually assume Hicks or Harrod neutrality.

But does anyone know if there is a single academic source paper that proved or pointed out this identification issue under Cobb Douglas.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the following is useful:

Sato (1970), The Estimation of Biased Technical Progress and the Production Function, International Economic Review, 11, 179-208

[JSTOR link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2525662)

Comment: For an overview, see also Acemoglu's (2009) textbook, especially Section 2.7.2 on "Types of Neutral Technological Progress"

Comment: thanks guys. very helpful.